# Separator between status left and window list in tmux status bar?

Tags: tmux

I'm looking to set a separator between the status-left and window list sections of the tmux status bar. Is there something similar to how you can set a separator between windows with `setw -g window-status-separator string`? I want to set the background color of status-left and have some padding between that and the beginning of the window list.

For example, looking for a seperator like the ones between the windows but between status left (in blue) and the first window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you are after but in tmux 3.1c, I have this on .tmux.conf for magenta border:
`set -g pane-active-border-style 'bg=default fg=#FF00FF'`

Comment: Looking for seperators between parts of the status bar. I updated my question with more info.